# Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.Models.KeyVaultErrorException: 'Access denied to first party service.'

Tags: c#, azure, azure-keyvault

I am new to Azure Cloud and trying to follow one tutorial on how to connect with Azure Key Vault. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6l_kpygO0Ic) is the link for the tutorial.

`Program.cs`

```
    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) =>
        {
            var builtConfig = config.Build();
            var vaultName = builtConfig["VaultName"];
            var keyVaultClient = new KeyVaultClient(async (authority, resource, scope) =>
            {
                var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential(false);
                var token = credential.GetToken(
                    new Azure.Core.TokenRequestContext(
                        new[] { "https://vault.azure.net/.default" }));
                return token.Token;
            });
            config.AddAzureKeyVault(vaultName, keyVaultClient, new DefaultKeyVaultSecretManager());
        });
```

`appsettings.json`

```
"VaultName": "https://connectionstringkeyvault.vault.azure.net/"
```

In Azure, I have created a Key Vault with the name `ConnectionStringKeyVault` and I have defined a secret as well.

[image]

This is the access policy that I have created in Key Vault:

[image]

And, I have created a storage account with the following details:

[image]

But, whenever I try to execute my code I am getting the below exception:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: did oyu configure azure service authentication in visual studio ? tools -> options -> azure service authentication. you need to specify the account that has access to key vault.

Comment: @Thomas - Yes, it's configured but I am still getting the issue. Any other suggestion, you can suggest me to work on?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:**

To fix access denied you need to configure Active Directory permissions. Grant access to KeyVault.

**1.** Using PowerShell Run the command:

```
Set-AzureRmKeyVaultAccessPolicy -VaultName 'XXXXXXX' -ServicePrincipalName XXXXX -PermissionsToKeys decrypt,sign,get,unwrapKey
```

**2.**  Using the Azure portal

- Open Key Vaults
- Select **Access Policies** from the Key Vault resource blade.
- Click the **[+ Add Access Policy]** button at the top of the blade
- Click Select Principal to select the application you created earlier

[image]

- From the Key permissions **drop down, select "Decrypt", "Sign", "Get",
  "UnwrapKey"** permissions
- Save changes

**Solution 2:**

According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/identity-readme, Try with  replacing the `DefaultAzureCredential` with `ChainedTokenCredential`, the key value secret was successfully retrieved.

Example  code:

```
var cred = new ChainedTokenCredential(new ManagedIdentityCredential(), new AzureCliCredential());
SecretClient client = new SecretClient(new Uri(keyvaultUri), cred);
Response<KeyVaultSecret> secret = await client.GetSecretAsync("kv-sec-test");
```

For more details refer this [document](https://www.rahulpnath.com/blog/connect-net-core-to-azure-key-vault-in-ten-minutes/)